# Powerpoint animations run independently

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, animation

Can I have 2 animations run independently in a PPT Slide?

ie: I want to have a countdown clock(1 animation of a rectangle slowly appearing over a one min frame) run at the same time as having questions appear on a slide by clicking?  The questions are dependent one one another by clicking.  I have both animations setup