# Continue one animation as you start the next in PowerPoint

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

I have one animation I need to start close to the beginning of a slide that should run for ~45 seconds slowly panning over a long strip of images, let's call this #1.

Easy.

But I need to sequentially "click" in other images while it runs. And here's the problem. Because as soon as I "click", animation #1 "skips" to the end and stays static.

How can I "decouple" animation #1 from subsequent clicks, so it will continue running until it ends or the slide changes?

This is probably related to [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1275130/powerpoint-animations-run-independently), but here were no answers since 2017, so I thought it was OK to ask again :)

Answer (score 0):

The answer is in the Microsoft article
[Add animation to slides](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/add-animation-to-slides%E2%80%8B-7db07067-4d78-40b5-bc87-5ff4f5ff6ff7):

> **Manage animations and effects**
>
> There are different ways to start animations in your presentation:
>
> - **On Click** - Start an animation when you click a slide.
> - **With Previous** - Play an animation at the same time as the previous animation in your sequence.
> - **After Previous** - Start an animation immediately after the previous one happens.
> - **Duration** - Lengthen or shorten an effect.
> - **Delay** - Add time before an effect runs.

You need to use "With Previous" as the starting animation effect.

Comment: Well, then two of them start at the same time. But as soon as I click to get the next animation, animation #1 "completes". Plus, animation #2, #3, etc. should not start at the beginning, #1 should run alone for a while (and I won't know how long until I'm actually there talking)

Comment: Seems like "With Previous" is truly implemented to tie the two animations together.

Comment: One "semi-solution" is to select `Repeat: Until End of Slide` under `Timing`. It's not perfect, as it will start over if it finishes. But until then it works as it should; the image strip continues to scroll throughout clicks to start other animations.